# Review Queue - Edit made but not accepted. How do I proceed?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

So I've been reviewing the '**First Posts**' queue lately. More often than not a question / answer will pop up in front of me that requires an edit before I'm happy to select 'Im Done'.

However, the question already has an edit pending, so I cannot add an edit. What do I do at this point?

The question / answer (in its current state) does not warrant me selecting '**No Action Needed**' and I don't want to '**Skip**' as it clearly needs work. I find myself leaving a comment or I could just downvote, but I don't feel this is always warranted, the question just needs a little bit of work.

What would you suggest is the best way to handle these? As an edit has been suggested, should I just be selecting '**No Action Needed**'...?

Comment: I usually open the post in a new tab, Skip, then edit it in the other tab.

Comment: Or gain some more rep to be able to review edits so you can use "Improve" to improve pending edit.